# Custom DNS with Azure and Namecheap

Tags: domain-name-system, azure

I found this article regarding custom DNS and GoDaddy

http://blog.smarx.com/posts/custom-domain-names-in-windows-azure

Does anyone know how to configure this properly in Namecheap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never used namecheap, but all you need to do is create a CNAME record to point your www.customename.com to azureappname.cloudapp.net